# How do I get my game to loop? Beginner Python

Tags: python

I am taking an online Python for beginners class and this is a class project. It has several issues, but I'm working on one at a time. The first being the loop. The game runs appropriately for the most part, and at the end asks the player if they would like to play again. If they say no, it needs to display game stats (this works). If they say yes, it needs to loop back to "Please choose a number between 1 and 20." That is not happening.

```
import time
import random
from statistics import mode, median, mean 

game_solution = random.randint(1, 20)
attempt = 5

#def start_game():

print("Welcome to Lindsey's Guessing Game!")
time.sleep(1)

play_game = input("Would you like to play? Yes or No  ")

if play_game.lower() == "no":
    print("Have a great day!")
    exit

if play_game.lower() == "yes":
    guesses = []
    print("Please choose a number between 1 and 20.  ")
    
#    try:
#        raise ValueError()

#    except ValueError as err:
#        print("Please enter a valid number.".format(err))
    
    while attempt > 0:
        player_guess = int(input(""))
        
        if player_guess < game_solution:
            print("Nope, too low! Guess again:  ")
            
        elif player_guess > game_solution:
            print("Nope, too high! Guess again:  ")
            
        else:
            print("You guessed it! Nice job!")
            exit
#            play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Yes or No  ")
        
        attempt -= 1
        guesses.append(player_guess)
    
    if attempt == 0:
        print("Sorry, you are out of guesses. The answer was {}.".format(game_solution))
        time.sleep(1)

play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Yes or No  ")

if play_again.lower() == "yes":
            play_game
    
if play_again.lower() == "no":

    print("You made {} guesses.".format(len(guesses)))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Your mode guess was {}.".format(round(mode(guesses))))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Your median guess was {}.".format(round(median(guesses))))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Your mean guess was {}.".format(round(mean(guesses))))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Thanks for playing! Have a great day :)")
```

I tried this second version which I suspect is closer but I can't get the game to run beyond asking if the user wants to play.

Appreciate any advice :)

```
import time
import random
from statistics import mode, median, mean 

game_solution = random.randint(1, 20)
attempt = 5

print("Welcome to Lindsey's Guessing Game!")
time.sleep(1)

play_game = input("Would you like to play? Yes or No  ")

if play_game.lower() == "no":
    print("Have a great day!")
    exit

if play_game.lower() == "yes":
    
    def start_game():
        
        while True:
            guesses = []
            print("Please choose a number between 1 and 20.  ")
            
        #    try:
        #        raise ValueError()
        
        #    except ValueError as err:
        #        print("Please enter a valid number.".format(err))
            
            while attempt > 0:
                player_guess = int(input(""))
                
                if player_guess < game_solution:
                    print("Nope, too low! Guess again:  ")
                    
                elif player_guess > game_solution:
                    print("Nope, too high! Guess again:  ")
                    
                else:
                    print("You guessed it! Nice job!")
                    exit
        #            play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Yes or No  ")
                
                attempt -= 1
                guesses.append(player_guess)
            
            if attempt == 0:
                print("Sorry, you are out of guesses. The answer was {}.".format(game_solution))
                time.sleep(1)
        
        play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Yes or No  ")
        
        if play_again.lower() == "yes":
                    start_game
            
        if play_again.lower() == "no":
        
            print("You made {} guesses.".format(len(guesses)))
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Your mode guess was {}.".format(round(mode(guesses))))
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Your median guess was {}.".format(round(median(guesses))))
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Your mean guess was {}.".format(round(mean(guesses))))
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Thanks for playing! Have a great day :)")
```

Comment: Just wrap the whole thing with a `while True`. `break` when the user don't want to play anymore...

Comment: "but I can't get the game to run beyond asking if the user wants to play." This is when you start debugging your code. Debugging is a critical skill to learn. This means tracing through your code and inspecting the values of variables. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) gives some great tips to get you started.

Comment: With that said, you need a `while` instead of `if`. You should google "python while loop" to learn more about how it works.